# Disable ATI card on Acer Timeline 5810TG

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card, bios, amd-graphics-card

This laptop has a huge problem: The switchable graphic card system (INTEL / ATI) can be configured in BIOS to use the ATI or the INTEL+ATI, but not the INTEL (low power).

I want to move on to Windows 8 and don't want to be (cannot!) stuck with specific drivers made to switch between both cards.

Anyone knows a workaround? Searched for a **BIOS MOD** (they exist, but only found for the 3810 model)

I really need to **disable de ATI card so it does not draw any power** when running on batteries.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried only installing the Intel drivers and leaving the AMD/ATI GPU drivers uninstalled.  If that doesn't work then you are out of luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop switchable graphics from switching to high-power GPU when charging the laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/298383/how-to-stop-switchable-graphics-from-switching-to-high-power-gpu-when-charging-t), Related: [How to turn off ATI adapter on Acer Timeline 4810G with Ubuntu 9.10](http://superuser.com/questions/64322/how-to-turn-off-ati-adapter-on-acer-timeline-4810g-with-ubuntu-9-10)

Comment: Not a duplicate! I don't want to remove the device on the SO... it would still **DRAW POWER**. I want to fully disable the device.

Answer (score 0):

I found a MODDED BIOS that permits the selection between INTEGATED / ATI:
http://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=17:38124:288#288
http://www.mediafire.com/?8jdklwcjovofzp6

I can see now why ACER did not release such an option: **The 5810TG won't reboot properly if INTEGRATED is selected!** (works fine though, as the SO recognizes only 1 card, and the other will presumably will stay turned off, not drawing any power).